# OpenLayers 3 how to get only the modified feature?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a problem with OL3 and it's ol.interaction.Modify Event. Whenever I modify a feature, just one, it returns all features inside the layer. Currently I have 77 features (polygons) and I can modify them with the modify interaction. Inside the callback function it returns the event with the feature member array and this seems to be buggy:

```
modify.on('modifyend', function(e) {

    console.log('=== Modify end ===');
    var modifiedFeature = e.features.item(0);

    //Why do I get 77 modified features if I have only touched one?
    // e.features size is = 77
    console.log(e.features);
});
```

Do you know a working way to get the one modified feature?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess you pass all the features to the modify interaction. That is why it returns all of them (If you dont provide your code I can only guess). You can always use a select interaction and then pass the selected feature to modify interction.
For your case you may iterate through your features and check for the revision,
each time a feature is modified, its version number will be incremented.

So do something like this

```
var modifiedFeatures;
modify.on('modifyend', function(e) {
    var features = e.features.getArray();
    console.log(features.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
        var rev = features[i].getRevision();
        if (rev > 1) {
            console.log("feature with revision:" + rev + " has been modified");
            modifiedFeatures.push(features[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/Luuwmq50/).

Comment: Hi Pavlos,

yes your are right, I pass all features and so it returns all features.

Thanks very much for the hint with the Revision number. This resolved my problem.

Comment: glad to help amigo!!

Comment: It's becoming horrible when you have to save the features. The revision indexes increase each time, then you cannot count on it. Too bad there isn't a more simple solution...

Comment: You can create an array of ids and place the modified feature ids there. Then each time you save you may empty the array. The example provided presents a way to catch the modified fetaure, there are several ways to achieve your goal but it depends on your logic