# Get Modified Feature from Modify Interaction

Tags: openlayers

**THIS QUESTION IS STILL OPEN AND OF INTEREST**

---

**Openlayers: 4.6.5**

---

I have a Modify Interaction and two active Select Interactions. The Modify Interaction is instantiated like this:

```
   var interaction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
     source: myLayer.getSource()
   });
```

When I click the edge of a polygon feature, a vertex of this polygon is highlighted - when I draw, the vertex is moved and when I release, the MODIFYEND is triggered. There is obviously exactly one feature affected.

---

After Modifying a Feature Geometry with the Modify Interaction, I expect the triggered `modifyend` event to provide **the feature or the geometry that has been affected by the modification**. However, it only provides me an ol.Collection containing ALL Features of the interaction's source.

How can I obtain the feature then?

```
interaction.on(ol.interaction.ModifyEventType.MODIFYEND,function(event) {

    // event does not have a feature property

});
```

---

**Edit: I totally want to avoid this:** 
I found this as a working solution, but I am not happy about it and I don't think this is the appropriate way:

```
interaction.on(ol.interaction.ModifyEventType.MODIFYEND,function(event) {

       var featureModified = interaction.dragSegments_[0][0].feature;

    });</s>
```

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175784/openlayers-3-how-to-get-only-the-modified-feature

Comment: Unfortunately, that thread does not answer the question

Comment: "You can always use a select interaction and the pass the selected feature to modify interaction" answers it perfectly.  See https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jgNGVQ  When you click on a country and modify its outline the country info is shown. `toggleCondition: ol.events.condition.never` is set in the select interaction so only one feature can be selected at a time.

Comment: I already have an active Select Interaction that I use for other purposes, so basically no.

Comment: Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842671/openlayers-4-modify-interaction-multiple-feature-at-the-same-coordinate/45859211#45859211 this avoids using a select interaction https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eqOLJV

Comment: The example (features.item(0)) does not deliver the modified feature but any feature coincidentally set on position 0.

Comment: Adding the pointemove listener is also not possible, since modifying the source affects my map and other interactions.

Comment: Using a select interaction with `multi: false` (the default) and `toggleCondition: ol.events.condition.never` ensures there will only be one feature available to the modify interaction so `features.item(0)` will be the modified featured.  How can the pointermove listener updating a source (you could also use a feature collection) reserved for the modify interaction which isn't used by anything else affect any other interactions?